# How to filter dynamic linq query on the initial data when there is self-join

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I have a query that I generate by dynamic linq. The problem is when I self-join the initial data set, all other filters are on the latest table. I want it to be on the initial. How can I do that? Here is an example:

```
var result = dataContext.Person;
var initialData = result;
....
var subQuery = initialData.Where(String.Format(predicateEntityIn, entityPropertyName), subSelection);
report = report.Join(subQuery, propertyName, propertyName, "inner");
...
```

Then I want to filter the initial data on a parameter

```
report = report.Where(String.Format("{0} = {1}", "PersonId", paramValue));
```

If I don't have the inner join then the query is correctly filtered, but with the inner join it does the filtering on the latest query of the initial type and also the select is on the latest table. The query that is generated is something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [t2].[Field1], [t2].[PersonId], [t2].[Field2]
FROM [dbo].[PersonDetails] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS [t1] ON [t1].[PersonId] = [t0].[PersonId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PersonDetails] AS [t2] ON [t0].[PersonId] = [t2].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t2].[YearOfBirth] = 2012)
```

But I want it to be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[Field1], [t0].[PersonId], [t0].[Field2]
FROM [dbo].[PersonDetails] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS [t1] ON [t1].[PersonId] = [t0].[PersonId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PersonDetails] AS [t2] ON [t0].[PersonId] = [t2].[PersonId]
WHERE ([t0].[YearOfBirth] = 2012)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line

```
report = report.Join(subQuery, propertyName, propertyName, "inner");
```

it should be

```
report = report.Join(subQuery, propertyName, propertyName, "outer");
```